# SQL Increment number in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have an issue where I need group a set of values and increase the group number when the variance between 2 columns is greater than or equal to 4, please see below.

UPDATE: I added a date column so you can view the order, but I need the group to update based off of the variance not the date.

`+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------------+
 |  Date  | Col 1 | Col 2 | Variance | Group Number |
 +--------+-------+-------+----------+--------------+
 | 1-Jun  |     2 |     1 |        1 |            1 |
 | 2-Jun  |     1 |     1 |        0 |            1 |
 | 3-Jun  |     3 |     2 |        1 |            1 |
 | 4-Jun  |     4 |     1 |        3 |            1 |
 | 5-Jun  |     5 |     1 |        4 |            2 |
 | 6-Jun  |     1 |     1 |        0 |            2 |
 | 7-Jun  |    23 |    12 |       11 |            3 |
 | 8-Jun  |    12 |    11 |        1 |            3 |
 | 9-Jun  |     2 |     1 |        1 |            3 |
 | 10-Jun |    13 |     4 |        9 |            4 |
 | 11-Jun |     2 |     1 |        1 |            4 |
 +--------+-------+-------+----------+--------------+`

Comment: Do you have an ID field to sort by?  Data in SQL server is NOT natively ordered ...

Comment: Thanks for editing my code, I actually was in the process of fixing that, but yes, it's ordered by date, but the number that dictates the group is the variance

Comment: What version of SQL Server? This is easier in SQL Server 2012 and up, pretty cumbersome on earlier versions (search for gaps and islands and you'll see what I mean). If you're displaying all of these rows - in a loop - on the client, maybe you could apply this group number during that loop too.

Answer (score 2):

The group number is simply the number of times that 4 or greater appears in the `variance` column.  You can get this using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from table t2
        where t2.date < t.date and t2.variance >= 4
       ) as GroupNumber
from table t;
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can also do this using a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when variance >= 4 then 1 else 0 end) over
            (order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
            ) as GroupNumber
from table t;
```

Comment: thanks! I'll give this a try, unfortunately we're on sql server 2008, but thanks for the suggestion on 2012